# Clarification about MyBatis resultMaps

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

Can somebody help clarify renaming properties/columns as defined by the MyBatis documentation?

**MyBatis documentation**

The documentation defines a simple Java class:

```
public class User {
  private int id;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  ...
}
```

and the following:

> The great thing about ResultMaps is that you've already learned a lot
>   about them, but you haven't even seen one yet! These simple cases
>   don't require any more than you've seen here. Just for example sake,
>   let's see what this last example would look like as an external
>   resultMap, as that is another way to solve column name mismatches.
>
> ```
> <resultMap id="userResultMap" type="User">   
>   <id property="id" column="user_id" />   
>   <result property="username" column="user_name"/>
>   <result property="password" column="password"/> 
> </resultMap>
> ```
>
> And the statement that references it uses the resultMap attribute to
>   do so (notice we removed the resultType attribute). For example:
>
> ```
> <select id="selectUsers" resultMap="userResultMap">   
>   select user_id, user_name, password   
>   from some_table   
>   where id = #{id}
> </select>
> ```

**My Question**
Does the above mean that the POJO/Bean variables "username" and "password" are assigned to the database columns named user_name and hashed_password, and is this done in the same vein that they also write the following?

> ```
> <select id="selectUsers" resultType="User">
>   select
>     user_id             as "id",
>     user_name           as "userName",
>     hashed_password     as "password"
>   from some_table
>   where id = #{id}
> </select>
> ```

Comment: Your bean should have `setUsername(String)` and `setId(int)` and the mapper will invoke these setters

Comment: @aristotll - I know it's a little verbose. I updated to hopefully make things more clear.

I'm wanting to know if the <result property="username" column="user_name"/> means that the POJO variable, "username" is mapped to the database column "user_name"

Comment: @lance-java - This was literally copy/pasted from the MyBatis documentation XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@physicsboy you are right in your last comment. Basically, the resultmap maps the column to the property. The resultmap 'sees' the last name you set the column, for example, if you make the following query:

```
select id, column_A from table
```

your resultmap would be

```
<resultMap id="ResultMapName" type="WhateverType">   
   <id property="id" column="id" />
   <result property="columnA" column="column_A"/>
</resultMap>
```

But if you set an alias to one of the columns:

```
select id, column_A as column_A_with_alias from table
```

Your resultMap would be

```
<resultMap id="ResultMapName" type="WhateverType">   
   <id property="id" column="id" />
   <result property="columnA" column="column_A_with_alias"/>
</resultMap>
```

No need to say that your POJO should have getters and setters for all properties.

Comment: ResultMap also has a property called autoMapping. When set to true, it can map automatically columns to properties whose names are the same. So there is no need to set all the <result>. As far as I know, the <id> is mandatory, even if the column are property names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
The result map tells MyBatis "take the value from column x in the query and store it in field y in the POJO.

Some more info:
MyBatis likes it when the fields in the POJO match the column names in the query.
When this is the case,
you don't need the resultMap entry.

You only need the resultMap when the fields in the POJO do not exactly match the column names in the query (this is the case in the example above "My Question" in your post).

Since the fields in the `User` POJO do not exactly match the column names in your second example ("hashedPassword" != "password") you still need to use a resultMap entry to map between the query and your POJO.

If you change the query as follows:

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="User">
  select
    user_id             as "id",
    user_name           as "username",
    hashed_password     as "hashedPassword"
  from some_table
  where id = #{id}
</select>
```

Then you will not need a resultMap,
because "username" is the actual field name in your POJO.